# how to check if a lustre directory has been set by chattr +P for project quota

Tags: quota, lustre

lustre doc wrote:

```
To limit quota usage for a specific project ID on a specific directory ("/mnt/testfs/dir" in this example), run:

$ chattr +P /mnt/testfs/dir
$ chattr -p 1 /mnt/testfs/dir
$ lfs setquota -p 1 -b 307200 -B 309200 -i 10000 -I 11000 /mnt/testfs
```

but if there are already lots of existing directories and I don't know whether they have been counted into project quota, how can I check if a given dir used be set the `chattr +P` and which project id it is linked to?

From another side, is there any method to quickly list all directory related to a given project id?

Comment: Have you check `lsattr`?

Comment: ```lsattr /lustre/path``` does not show any difference between project quota related dir and others. I'm not sure if it need some other option, at least -p or -P is not supported.